# combo charts in R mschart

Tags: r, powerpoint, mschart, officer

Is there a way to create combo charts using `mschart`. I am trying to create a chart where one column of the data will be a line chart and another column would be a bar chart. The below code doesnt work.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mschart)

mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "car") %>% 
  ms_linechart(x="car", y="mpg") %>% 
  ms_barchart(x="car", y = "qsec") %>% 
  print(preview = TRUE)
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
Error in mschart::ms_barchart(., x = "car", y = "qsec") : 
  y column should be numeric.
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "combo chart?" Do you mean overlapping?

Comment: Hey combo chart is what PowerPoint calls it when you have multiple types of traces in the same chart (so combinations of lines and bars in the same chart as an example)

Comment: Don't think it's possible. You can create word-editable figures with other packages that have all of the flexibility of R's graphics (ggplot etc.) but will not be linked to the data

Comment: I thought so. Unfortunately the work requires ppt editable charts or I would drop some ggplot/plotlys in there

Comment: Is it an Idea to have them on the same slide instead on one plot?

Comment: The OP knows how to put them on the same slide presumably. The issue is they want it to overlap.  However, my point was that you can use the `officer` and `rvg` packages to create powerpoint-editable figures, albeit they will not respond dynamically to the data. https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/02/editable-plots-from-r-to-powerpoint/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible in `mschart` to create a single figure that simultaneously overlays multiple types of traces onto a single plot. You can create multiple figures in the same page but not the combination figure. However, this is possible with the `officer` and `rvg` packages. The drawback of these is that the figure will not be connected to the data, such that a change in the data will affect the figure. However, the figure will nevertheless be editable within Word itself.